# Intellij hotswap - JSP does not redeploy

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, hotswap

I am doing exploded ear deployment in IntelliJ Idea.

Class changes hot-swap very well, but resource changes and jsp do not!

Looks like, they are being copied in right places when make/build is done to a project, but i don't see changes when I test it

I believe, since its ear and not war deployment, its not handled well.

When I redeploy, then changes are picked up

I tried - update classes and resources - on frame deactivation, that didn't seem to help

I am using weblogic 12.1.2